# How to sort the xml element based on data in wso2esb

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb.
I wish to transform the data using wso2esb i have done the issue is while response i am getting data in descending manner how would i arrange in to ascending way .

```
<response>
    <customer-details>
        <cusfirstname>Empire Burlesque</cusfirstname>
        <delarname>Bob Dylan</delarname>
        <cusno>254</cusno>
    </customer-details>
    <customer>
        <cusId>6</cusId>
        <customername>Bonnie Tyler</customername>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusId>8</cusId>
        <customername>Dolly Parton</customername>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusId>3</cusId>
        <customername>Gary Moore</customername>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusId>5</cusId>
        <customername>Eros Ramazzotti</customername>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>BMG</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusId>7</cusId>
        <customername>Bee Gees</customername>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1998</year>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusId>1</cusId>
        <customername>Dr.Hook</customername>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS</company>
        <price>8.10</price>
        <year>1973</year>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusId>2</cusId>
        <customername>Rod Stewart</customername>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Pickwick</company>
        <price>8.50</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusId>4</cusId>
        <customername>Andrea Bocelli</customername>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.80</price>
        <year>1996</year>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusId>12</cusId>
        <customername>Percy Sledge</customername>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Atlantic</company>
        <price>8.70</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusId>9</cusId>
        <customername>Savage Rose</customername>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Mega</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1995</year>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusId>11</cusId>
        <customername>Many</customername>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Grammy</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1999</year>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <cusId>10</cusId>
        <customername>Kenny Rogers</customername>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Mucik Master</company>
        <price>8.70</price>
        <year>1995</year>
    </customer>
</response>
```

I wish to arrange the **customer** tag data in ascending order based on **cusId** so how would i arrange this I tried with xquery but i couldn't find the any function regarding element sorting , cusId should be appear  in 1,2,3,...

How would i achieve this i know there is no function in xpath for this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT you can use `<xsl:sort>` when using `<xsl:apply-templates>` for each `customer`. This stylesheet orders the customers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="response">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="customer-details"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="customer">
                <xsl:sort select="cusId"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

*"I tried with xquery but i couldn't find the any function regarding element sorting"*

In XQuery you use `order by` for sorting:

```
for $i in /response/customer
order by $i/cusId
return $i
```